# AJAX fails loading XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I try to reach out to the IKEA Api to access the availability checker. If I want to ajax the file it wont return anything and the .fail function is called.

```
$('#availability').submit(function (event) { 
let productNumber = $('#productId').val();

if (testString(productNumber, '^[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2}$')) {
    productNumber = productNumber.replace(/\./g, '');
    let target = 'http://ikea.com/de/de/iows/catalog/availability/' + productNumber;

    $.ajax({
        url: target,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'xml'
    })
        .done(function (data) {
            console.log('succes');

        })
        .fail(function (x) {
            console.log(x);
        });
}

event.preventDefault();
```

});

Comment: isn't it dataType: 'text/xml' ?

Comment: that doesnt change a thing.

Comment: "Does not work"... What does this mean? Are you getting an error? Is nothing returned? Stack Overflow does not support IKEA's API...

Comment: Sorry for my short description, im basically tired to death atm. It wont return anything. I also dont get an error or maybe I try to get the error on the wrong way.

Comment: Since you are tired perhaps you need one of these http://www.ikea.com/de/de/iows/catalog/availability/S99006965. The API works - are you sure you setting the code correctly? It is not exactly the product code displayed on the page with all the dots. Test it with the code of a product in the URL (as my example). They seem to start with an S but that may not always be the case. The beds do!

Comment: Indeed it works fine. http://www.ikea.com/de/de/iows/catalog/availability/20282942/ works fine for me too and its exactly what I am looking for. But if I try to GET from this url via ajax it wont return anything...

Answer (score 0):

You don't see any result because your request is being blocked (here is the error that I see in the console):

**XMLHttpRequest for http://ikea.com/de/de/iows/catalog/availability/00122822/ required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).**

**Redirect was blocked for CORS request**

There are several links related to CORS error in StackOverflow. Apparently, this is a security setting in your browser and it is unsafe to turn it off.

I found this link that suggests a workaround: 
https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/